# update with reg ex or

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a mssql database and I'm trying to update a database field that has data like so..

**1111-2222-3333-4444**

I want to go through all the records and change the first 3 sets of numbers and leave the last one in place.

So, after the update they would all be **0000-0000-0000-4444** with the **4444** being what is was before.

How can I do this?

Comment: is there always 4 numbers in the end?

Comment: no, that just show the 4 sets of 4 numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all rows are in exactly the same format and you wish to change the first three groups of characters to exactly the same value in each row, then something like this would work:

```
update tblToUpdate
set columnToUpdate = '0000-0000-0000-' + right(columnToUpdate , 4)
```

Definitely make a backup of that table before doing anything too crazy!

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tmp (a varchar(32))

insert into tmp values ('1111-2222-3333-4444')
GO

select '0000-0000-0000-' + substring(a, 16, 4)
from tmp
```